# How to remove microsoft email account from setting?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am using windows 8.1 phone and I have configured email+account and now I want to remove that account from my phone but I dont no how to do that.

[image]

Any Idea? I will thankful If you guide me for removing email account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove microsoft account, because this is the main account of a device. Device reset is required.

Comment: Any other way to replace with main account?

Comment: Apps, settings, internet passwords and a lot more stuff is connected to the main account. So it's normal to reset the device to change it.